# Google Speech to text: The video model is currently not supported for language : nl-NL

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Url used: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/

I uploaded a wav audio file (exported both as mp3/wav/flac) via audacity.

I Selected "nederlands" (dutch), punctiation can be both on or of and uploaded the export.

First it uploads, gives me the 'transcribing' message and after that:

```
The video model is currently not supported for language : nl-NL
```

I see in the console of my browser window:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
speech.min.js:1132 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid recognition 'config': The video model is currently not supported for language : nl-NL.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

cxl-services.appspot.com/proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fspeech.googleapis.com%2Fv1p1beta1%2Fspeech%3Arecognize Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
speech.min.js:1132 A server error occurred!
```

If I use the microphone to record a message it works properly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem for me using the `video` model for `fr-FR`

Answer (score 1):

The speech-to-text API provides four different models to choose from:

- video
- phone_call
- command_and_search
- default

(https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#select-model)

Not all models are available for all languages. Try using the `default` model for `fr-FR` or `nl-NL`.
I had the same issue with `de-DE`. It wouldn't work with the `video` model, but using the `default` model worked.